# Как проверить, повторяются ли свойства объекта?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Есть объект:

```
{
      "a":[
         {
            name: "name",
            id: "id",
            rect: "rect"
         },
         {
            name:"noname",
            id: "123478123564187"
            rect:"notRect"
         },
         {
            name:"name",
            id: "id",
            rect:"rect"
         }
      ]
}
```

Как проверить, есть ли повторяющиеся свойства?

Comment: нужно взять два объекта, пройтись по их свойствам и сравнить. Повторяются имена свойств или значения?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy